# android.net.Uri ambiguous authority or path

Tags: java, android, uri

Given the following Android Java code:

```
import android.net.Uri;
String humanEnteredString = "google.com";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(humanEnteredString);
```

Why is `uri.getPath() == "google.com"`, and not `uri.getAuthority()`?
How to force Uri.parse to see "google.com" as the authority?

Is that what classes like this are for?
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/WebAddress.java

Why is this `WebAddress` class not accessible in the Android SDK?

Is there any pre-built class that can generate a valid `<scheme>://<authority><path>` browsable Uri from a human entered string that may be missing the scheme?

Obviously, I can test for and prefix "http[s]://" as necessary/appropriate, but shouldn't there already be a bulletproof class that does this already?

Thanks,
Pv

Comment: Could you pick a single question and ask it alone?  Otherwise people might mark it as "too broad" and you may get no answer.

Comment: My questions are all related on a single [hopefully] clear topic. If I get an answer to my first few Qs, then the last few are moot. Thanks for the feedback, but it is a little bit ridiculous to suggest a precedent that everyone on SO should break up a posting of a reasonable number of multiple related questions in to individual postings with a single question each.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is uri.getPath() == "google.com", and not uri.getAuthority()?

Because `"google.com"` is not a valid `Uri`.

> How to force Uri.parse to see "google.com" as the authority?

Use a valid `Uri`: one with a scheme, such as `https://google.com`.

> Is there any pre-built class that can generate a valid :// browsable Uri from a human entered string that may be missing the scheme?

Not in the Android SDK, at least that I can recall.

Comment: Thanks, but I would think that since ```Uri.parse("google.com")``` returns a Uri, then "google.com" is a valid Uri. I understand the point and syntax of hierarchical and opaque Uris and my flawed premise of my expecting "google.com" to magically be recognized as an authority and not a path, but I am trying to parse a human entered string that is passed to my public API method, and after >20 years of professional programming I am constantly amazed at how many simple things still require thousands of developers to write/copy the same duplicate code. I'll just copy the code from WebAddress.java.

Comment: @swooby: "I would think that since Uri.parse("google.com") returns a Uri, then "google.com" is a valid Uri" -- not according to [the IETF specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), which has "The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be empty (no characters)".